# How to write `damn it` in a better way for a third person?

Tags: writing

I don't want to write `Damn It`.
Instead I want to write something like -> `He squeezed his eyes with an expression of 'shit-I-forgot'`

You know, like ->
She: Hey, how are you?
He: Hey, I'm good. What's up?
She: Did you do the homework?
He: Damn it! I forgot.

But in my case, the character doesn't say anything, just makes the expression one would make in such a scenario. How can I better phrase it?

Comment: The usual way to spell it in dialog is _Dammit_ (capital and exclamation point optional).

Comment: He paled and felt a sinking feeling in the pit of his stomach.

Comment: How about _He grimaced_?

Comment: Thank you people. These are good ideas.